# Cannot watch array values in JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array of strings named `resul` that I want to transform into JSON. I try two ways to achieve it.

The first one I use the following commands:

```
$this -> resul = json_encode(utf8_encode($this -> sqry -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)));
```

But I have the warning:

> Warning: utf8_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

So I know I must convert this array into string. That's the second way to achieve my goal. That's the code I use:

```
$this -> resul = $this -> sqry -> fetchAll();

for($i=0;$i<count($this -> resul);$i++)
{
    $this -> fresul = $this -> fresul . $this -> resul[$i]["nombre"];
    $this -> fresul = $this -> fresul . $this -> resul[$i]["descripcion"];
    $this -> fresul = $this -> fresul . $this -> resul[$i]["precio"];
    $this -> fresul = $this -> fresul . $this -> resul[$i]["foto"];
}

$this -> fresul = utf8_encode($this -> fresul);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo "</br>" . json_encode($this -> fresul);
```

`fresul` is the string of array `resul`. After running the script I get the error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

But if I delete the header I only have a String but no errors nor warnings.

How can I transform this array into JSON?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this:

$data = $this->db->get($table)->result_array();
        
        echo json_encode( array('data' => $data) );

Comment: Why do you use `utf8_encode` in the first place? If your database is not returning UTF-8, set your connection encoding to UTF-8 instead of using this kludge. And prepending JSON with a `</br>` makes it *not JSON*.

Answer (score 0):

If your database doesn't return UTF-8 encoded text, then adjust your database to return UTF-8 encoded text instead. Then you don't need `utf8_encode`. In fact, any time you're tempted to use `utf8_encode`, it's a sign that something else is going wrong with your handling of encodings.

For PDO:

```
// somewhere:
$this->db = new PDO('mysql:...;charset=utf8mb4');

// then:
$this->resul = json_encode($this->sqry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Et voilà, the database returns UTF-8 encoded data which can directly be JSON encoded.

Comment: Thanks for answers. After trying what you typed and failed I changed fetchAll for fetch and I obtained every row in a variable and saved it in the array resul.